# Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage Whitelist Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am updating to activestorage in rails 5.2 and am getting a "
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass" in my create action.
I think the problem has to do with my whitelisted params. I tried to follow the guides but still cannot figure out what I am missing.

My model has   has_many_attached :images
My controller has

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.images.attach(params[:product][:images])

    if @product.save
      redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
private
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :category_id, :tag_list, :partialone, :partialtwo, :partialthree, :shape, :earrings, :metalweight, :sizeone, :sizetwo, :metal, :totalweightone, :totalweighttwo, :meleequant, review_attributes: [:id, :rating, :text, :author, :name], images: [] )
    end
```

Here is the full trace:
acts-as-taggable-on (5.0.0) lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:206:in `process_dirty_object'
acts-as-taggable-on (5.0.0) lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:184:in`set_tag_list_on'
acts-as-taggable-on (5.0.0) lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb:45:in `tag_list='
activemodel (5.2.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:51:in`public_send'
activemodel (5.2.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:51:in `_assign_attribute'
activemodel (5.2.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:44:in`block in _assign_attributes'
activemodel (5.2.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:43:in `each'
activemodel (5.2.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:43:in`_assign_attributes'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:23:in `_assign_attributes'
activemodel (5.2.1) lib/active_model/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in`assign_attributes'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:314:in `initialize'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in`new'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:66:in `new'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:52:in`create!'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:65:in `create'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in`send_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in`process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in`run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in`process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in`block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in`instrument'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in`process_action'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in`process'
actionview (5.2.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in`dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in`dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in`block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in`serve'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in`block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in`call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in`call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in`context'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in`call'
activerecord (5.2.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in`block in call'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in`call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in`call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in`block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in`call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
railties (5.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in`block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in`tagged'
railties (5.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in`call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
request_store (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in`call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in`call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in`call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in`call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
webpacker (3.5.5) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:22:in`perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.4) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (5.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in`call'
rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in`service'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:290:in`block in start_thread'

For some reason, I think the problem is with "images: []" in the whitelisted params but am not sure. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: show the stacktrace, perhaps?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev included.

Comment: Good call. The problem was with another gem (acts as taggable). It needed to be upgraded in order to work with Rails 5.2.